# Disable multiple tabs at once

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, wizard, twitter-bootstrap-wizard

I am using [Twitter bootstrap wizard plugin](https://github.com/VinceG/twitter-bootstrap-wizard) to make a step by step wizard. I have written functions on document ready to disable all the tabs except the first tab. This is how I have it:

```
$('#rootwizard').bootstrapWizard('disable', '1');
$('#rootwizard').bootstrapWizard('disable', '2');
$('#rootwizard').bootstrapWizard('disable', '3');
```

More details on how to disable can be found [here](http://vadimg.com/twitter-bootstrap-wizard-example/examples/remove-step.html)

I don't prefer this ways because when I have like 10 tabs I have to write disable code for each of them. So is there a way to maybe pass all the tab indices in the parameters? So that I can get it done with just one line of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the docs:

```
Disables a tab, disallows a user to click it (adds .disabled to the li element)
```

So, reasonably, you can just add `class="disabled"` to any of the tabs you want disabled on page load.

As for passing them all via the function, the plugin does not support that.